# Сводная кросс-таблица ms sql

Tags: sql

Не хватает знаний в области скриптов sql.

Есть бд с вот такими таблицами и полями.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Основная таблица хранения Units. В ней же стоят ключи связки с остальными таблицами. Суть проблемы - хотелось бы сделать некое подобие сводной таблицы, в котором нужно вывести пересечение взаимовстречаеммости. Результат нужен похожим вот на это . Необязательно закрашено, можно и "Х" ставить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно ли реализовать?

Comment: [FROM — использование PIVOT и UNPIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16)